# gdal.Open is giving none

Tags: python, modis

I am having some problem with Gdal.open with my list of raster. I use Python 3 with GDAL 2.2.

This is my script:

```
import os
import glob
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.ndimage
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt



inDir = 'C:/Doy2000/'
os.chdir(inDir)  
#repertoir sorti 

outDir = os.path.normpath(os.path.split(inDir)[0] + os.sep + 'output') + '\\' 
if not os.path.exists(outDir): os.makedirs(outDir)

# Create list of MODIS rasters for surface reflectance
modis_EVI = glob.glob('MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_**.tif')

evi = gdal.Open(modis_EVI[0])
```

I don't know what I can do. When I do print(modis_EVI ) and print(evi) I had :

```
print(modis_EVI)
['MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000209_aid0001.tif', 'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000225_aid0001.tif', 'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000241_aid0001.tif', 'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000257_aid0001.tif', 'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000273_aid0001.tif', 'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000289_aid0001.tif', 'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000305_aid0001.tif', 'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000321_aid0001.tif', 'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000337_aid0001.tif', 'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000353_aid0001.tif']

print(modis_EVI[0])
MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_doy2000209_aid0001.tif
print(evi)
None
```

What can I do for this error? How can I control this error?

Comment: is this script within an IDE like pycharm or spyder?

Comment: @fluidmotion Spyder !

Comment: Try using the full path when opening the file

Comment: @gberard how can i use the path cause i trying to open liste of file evi = gdal.Open(modis_EVI[0]) is like that : evi = gdal.Open(C:/Doy2000/modis_EVI[0]) ?

Comment: Easiest way would probably be to modify the globbing: `modis_EVI = glob.glob(os.path.join(inDir, 'MOD13Q1.006__250m_16_days_EVI_*.tif'))`.  Also consider [telling gdal to raise exceptions](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/PythonGotchas#PythonbindingsdonotraiseexceptionsunlessyouexplicitlycallUseExceptions) instead of failing silently

Comment: @gberard i have the same output  `print(evi)
None`

Comment: What does `os.path.exists(modis_EVI[0])` return?

Comment: @MarcPfister  `os.path.exists(modis_EVI[0])
Out[2]: True`

Comment: does it produce the same output when ran as a standalone script outside of Spyder?

Comment: @fluidmotion but i don't know how i can do script outside of spyder i know just spyder

Comment: i can undersant what is the problem

Comment: there are several sites that give examples of running a script from command line: [wikihow](https://www.wikihow.com/Use-Windows-Command-Prompt-to-Run-a-Python-File) and [pythoncentral](https://www.pythoncentral.io/execute-python-script-file-shell/) are some of the first to come up on search.

Comment: here's another - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19779986/how-to-run-a-py-file-in-windows-command-line

Comment: okey but i need do this in spyder so need to work in spyder . you don't have any solution for gdal.open returs none ?

Comment: i've seen issues running GDAL with IDE's like spyder. i was trying to rule out a problem there first.

Comment: If i work with python outside spyder i need to install gdal in my windows outside anaconda because for spyder is so easy to install gdal with anaconda

Comment: As mentioned above, add `gdal.UseExceptions()` after you import gdal

Comment: problem resolu thanks all for help, is just problem with format(TIF)